# Syncronising Magento 1.9.1.0, 1.9.2.4 and Modman

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, modman

i am facing a task which seems to be some heavy manually work. I am about to install a new Magento Version 1.9.2.4 and migrate the old Shop from 1.9.1.0. The old Version has been hacked, so i have to set it up new.

What way to do that migration, not to have to compare every file and update it, plus update modman? And How is customizing done which is updatable?

Do you have some faq and hints for that?

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

When developing websites using Magento I try to keep the Magento code and my code separate so that if I need to update to a newer version of Magento it is "easy".

For this I have 2 private git repos:

1. My project repo,
2. Magento with git tag matching the magento version,

After this there a multiple ways to include the right version of Magento using git, modman, composer or a mixture of all three.

Currently I am using a custom composer set-up script that allows for a section like.

```
"magento-source": {
    "tag": "1.9.2.4",
    "url": "my-git-repo-url"
},
```

This will then checkout this repo into my public web directory. Later on composer will then link all my project repo into the web directory to create a complete project that I can then work with.

Taking this approach or similar means that I can simply update my Magento repo with the new version and then ask composer to include this newer version.

**Let Magento manage the Magento code and differences and let yourself focus on your own code.**

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade your current version follow below tutorial

```
    Upgrade magento to latest version / fire below commands and follow process

Magento File permissions:
chmod -R 644 ./*
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod 550 ./mage

Magento Upgrade version to latest version using command line:
Step 1
cd /magento_folder
#for example: cd /var/www/magento
touch maintenance.fla

Step 2
Back up all your files.

Step 3
cd /magento_folder
cd /magento_folder
rm -rf  var/cache/*   var/session/*
chmod -R 777 /magento_folder
chmod 550 ./mage
./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage list-installed

On clicking “Enter” key after inserting the command: ‘./mage list-installed’ in the command prompt, the Magento modules would be displayed in the manner as shown below:
Installed package for channel 'community' : Lib_Js_Ext           1.8.1.0 stable Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.1 stable Lib_Js_TinyMCE       3.4.7.0 stable Lib_Js_Calendar      1.51.1.1 stable Lib_Phpseclib        1.5.0.0 stable Lib_ZF               1.11.1.0 stable Lib_Js_Prototype     1.8.0.0.4 stable Lib_ZF_Locale        1.11.1.0 stable Mage_All_Latest      1.8.1.0 stable Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.8.1.0 stable Interface_Frontend_Default 1.8.1.0 stable Interface_Install_Default 1.8.1.0 stable Mage_Downloader      1.8.1.0 stable Mage_Centinel        1.8.1.0 stable Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.8.1.0 stable Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.2 stable Mage_Compiler        1.8.1.0 stable Magento_Mobile       1.8.1.0.23.1 stable Mage_Core_Adminhtml  1.8.1.0 stable Mage_Core_Modules    1.8.1.0 stable Lib_Varien           1.8.1.0 stable Lib_Google_Checkout  1.8.1.0 stable Lib_Js_Mage          1.8.1.0 stable Mage_Locale_en_US    1.8.1.0 stable Lib_Mage             1.8.1.0 stable Under rare situations wherein the modules are not listed as per the above format, you may use the below command to initiate the upgrade process: ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest –force Once your Magento modules get listed in the desired manner, opt for using the following commands: ./mage list-upgrades ./mage upgrade-all

Installed package for channel 'community' :
Lib_Js_Ext           1.8.1.0 stable
Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.1 stable
Lib_Js_TinyMCE       3.4.7.0 stable
Lib_Js_Calendar      1.51.1.1 stable
Lib_Phpseclib        1.5.0.0 stable
Lib_ZF               1.11.1.0 stable
Lib_Js_Prototype     1.8.0.0.4 stable
Lib_ZF_Locale        1.11.1.0 stable
Mage_All_Latest      1.8.1.0 stable
Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.8.1.0 stable
Interface_Frontend_Default 1.8.1.0 stable
Interface_Install_Default 1.8.1.0 stable
Mage_Downloader      1.8.1.0 stable
Mage_Centinel        1.8.1.0 stable
Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.8.1.0 stable
Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.3.2 stable
Mage_Compiler        1.8.1.0 stable
Magento_Mobile       1.8.1.0.23.1 stable
Mage_Core_Adminhtml  1.8.1.0 stable
Mage_Core_Modules    1.8.1.0 stable
Lib_Varien           1.8.1.0 stable
Lib_Google_Checkout  1.8.1.0 stable
Lib_Js_Mage          1.8.1.0 stable
Mage_Locale_en_US    1.8.1.0 stable
Lib_Mage             1.8.1.0 stable
Under rare situations wherein the modules are not listed as per the above format, you may use the below command to initiate the

upgrade process:
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest –force

Once your Magento modules get listed in the desired manner, opt for using the following commands:
./mage list-upgrades

./mage upgrade-all
```